# Constant not recognized in lisp formula within org-mode spreadsheet

Tags: org-mode, spreadsheet

Here is a simple org-mode spreadsheet in which the third column is computed in terms of the second column by multiplying it
by the exchange rate between Euros and Dollars (taken to be 1.23) thru the lisp formula `$3='(* $2 1.23)`

```
|---------+----------------+------------------|
| Produce | Price in Euros | Price in Dollars |
|---------+----------------+------------------|
| Apples  |           3.00 |             3.69 |
| Oranges |           3.50 |            4.305 |
| Pears   |           4.00 |             4.92 |
|---------+----------------+------------------|
#+TBLFM: $3='(* $2 1.23);N
```

I'd like to be able to store the exchange rate in a constant, such as in

```
#+CONSTANTS: exchange=1.23
```

and then use it in my table, namely

```
|---------+----------------+------------------|
| Produce | Price in Euros | Price in Dollars |
|---------+----------------+------------------|
| Apples  |           3.00 | #ERROR           |
| Oranges |           3.50 | #ERROR           |
| Pears   |           4.00 | #ERROR           |
|---------+----------------+------------------|
#+TBLFM: $3='(* $2 exchange);N
```

However I am getting an error.  It seems to me that in the new version of the formula, namely  `$3='(* $2 exchange)`, the
constant `exchange` is not being recognized.  And yes, I did press `C-c C-c` in the CONSTANTS line above to refresh the local setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(describe-variable 'org-table-formula-constants)`

```
#+TBLFM: $3='(* $2 $exchange);N
```